# How can I set the sslPolicy of the ApplicationLoadBalancer ApplicationListener that is created by ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Using the AWS CDK I create an `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` construct in my `Stack`.

This construct normally creates an `ApplicationLoadBalancer` and it's associated `ApplicationListener`.  Though the ALB is exposed via the `loadBalancer` property of the construct, the `ApplicationLoadBalancer` does not have a collection property for the `ApplicationListener`s that are created via the `addListener` method of the `ApplicationLoadBalancer`.  Therefore there is no direct way of setting the `sslPolicy` of the listener.

How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by subclassing `ApplicationLoadBalancer` and overriding the `addListener` method.  This implementation hard codes the `sslPolicy` but your subclass can be made configurable as needed.

```js
/**
 * An ApplicationLoadBalancer whose listener ssPolicy is set to SslPolicy.FORWARD_SECRECY_TLS12
 *
 * <p>The default ApplicationLoadBalancer sslPolicy is set to include TLS 1.1 and static ciphers.</p>
 * <p>ApplicationLoadBalancer's constructor properties do not include an option for specifying the default sslPolicy
 * used when the addListener method is called by other constructs such as ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService and
 * it also does not expose the listeners collection as a property so that the sslPolicy can be modified after the
 * fact.</p>
 * <p>We use this class to provide a means of consistently set the TLS version to corporate standards when using an ALB.</p>
 */
export class ApplicationLoadBalancerStandardized extends ApplicationLoadBalancer {

    public addListener(id: string, props: BaseApplicationListenerProps): ApplicationListener {
        // HACK: cast to any so we can override a "readonly" property.
        (props.sslPolicy as any) = SslPolicy.FORWARD_SECRECY_TLS12;
        return super.addListener(id, props);
    }
}
```

In use

```js
// We create the ALB explicitly rather than letting ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService (ALBFS)
// create it so that we can set the sslPolicy, which is not possible when the ALB is created with ALBFS.
// To match the ALB id that would be generated by ALBFS if it were to create the ALB, we must prefix
// the ALB id with the same id as the ALBFS.
const loadBalancer = new ApplicationLoadBalancerStandardized(this, `${this._props.serviceName}LB`, {
  vpc: cluster.vpc,
  internetFacing: this._props.publicLoadBalancer !== undefined ? this._props.publicLoadBalancer : true
});
const fargateService = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, this._props.serviceName, {
  cluster,
  loadBalancer,
  ...
  ...
```

See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11841 for any possible updates on the listener collection being provided on `ApplicationLoadBalancer`.